# My cogs file didn't load into my main file (discord.py)

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

it seems that cogs file does't work when I try to run my discord bot. I even try to use load in Discord. i already watch many videos regarding cogs and read documentation but I can't find any solution. Can anybody spot the mistake ?
Here is my cogs file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle


class UpdateCode(commands.Cog) :

  def _init_(self, client) :
    self.client = client

  @ commands.Cogs.listener()

  async def on_ready(self):
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(self.client))
    self.status_swap.start()
    self.status = cycle([
      " Unanswered Question of Life", 
    " Self - Referential Paradox", 
    " Near-infinite density?", 
    " Dark matter ?", 
    " Measurement of the speed of light in one straight line", 
    " Schrodinger's cat ???"
    "436c69636b2074686973206c696e6b20666f72206672656520766275636b7320212121212121203a200a68747470733a2f2f7777772e796f75747562652e636f6d2f77617463683f763d6451773477395767586351 (try to decrypt this)",
    "The light side of Discord is the path of many unnatural abilities"
    ])

  @ tasks.loop(minutes = 5)
  async def status_swap(self):
    await self.client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(next(self.status)))

def setup(client) :
  client.add_cog(UpdateCode(client))
```

Here is my main file

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from online import keep_alive

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@ client.command()
async def load(ctx,extension) :
  client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

@ client.command()
async def unload(ctx,extension) :
  client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs') :
  if filename.endswith('.py') :
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('MATH_VAR'))
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 606, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/runner/Math-Bot/cogs/update.py", line 6, in <module>
    class UpdateCode(commands.Cog) :
  File "/home/runner/Math-Bot/cogs/update.py", line 11, in UpdateCode
    @ commands.Cogs.listener()
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Cogs'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 678, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 609, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.update' raised an error: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Cogs'
```

If you know how to resolve this error, please comment on my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysing the error

Breaking down the first part of the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 606, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/runner/Math-Bot/cogs/update.py", line 6, in <module>
    class UpdateCode(commands.Cog) :
  File "/home/runner/Math-Bot/cogs/update.py", line 11, in UpdateCode

    # First hint which points to your code.
    @ commands.Cogs.listener()

# Second hint which points the problem in your code.
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Cogs'
```

### Referring existing code

Secondly, you can refer to the way the `UpdateCode` Cog is defined, it is based on `command.Cog` and not `command.Cogs`. `class UpdateCode(commands.Cog)` notice the missing **'s'**.

### Conclusion

Based on the first two points that I made, we can conclude that there was a slight mistake when you defined the `@ commands.Cogs.listener()` decorator by including **'s'** in the word **'Cog'**.

### References

- *https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener*